# How to use same entity in all the forms?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

please excuse me there is something wrong in this question.

My application uses Entity Framework. Most of my forms are master-detail-subdetail type. In my master form, I create an instance of the Entity as below :

```
DataTestEntities dbContext = new DataTestEntities();
```

and I use it for the linq queries as below:

```
objRec = dbContext.ProdInfoes.Where(p => p.ProdCode == oProducts.ProdCode).First();
```

I can pass the dbContext to the details screen using System.Reflection. The reason I am passing the dbContext is to avoid creating the instance of the entity over and over.

Is this a good approach? Does it create any performance issues?

Is there any other way that I can a common dbcontext? How about using a class library with the datamodel?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a little more code or information about what you're trying to do. You mentioned that you want to avoid creating an instance of an entity over and over again, but you're also talking about maintaining a single instance of the context. If you want to avoid recreating the entity, I don't see what would prevent you from just passing the entity instance directly to the detail form.

Comment: Separate view and data layer. It's harder to start with, but incredibly beneficial in the end. See patterns like MVC, MVVM. WPF was made for it! Your windows should not know anything about contexts whatsoever.